# No options in the "play sound through" box of sound settings

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10, and I'm an absolute Linux novice, so I apologize in advance for that.

My sound isn't working. The sound isn't muted. In sound settings there is nothing showing up in the "Play Sound Through" box.

My sound card is being recognized by the system and I have the sound modules installed.

Any advice on what to try next?

Comment: Do you get any errors on boot or whilst trying playing sound from command line, and what is the output of `cat /proc/asound/cards`?

Comment: I don't get any errors and when I enter that command I get this:
0 [HDMI               ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                                    HDA Intel HDMI at 0xb2210000 irq 47